# How To Stay Protected Against ListviewSelectedIndexChanged

Tags: c#, visual-studio

```
private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

     ListView lv = (ListView)sender;
     textBox2.Text = lv.FocusedItem.SubItems[3].Text;
     textBox3.Text = lv.FocusedItem.SubItems[0].Text;


}
```

I think the above code is not secure and this will fire **Null Reference Error** on updating  listview Items  by other forms so how to secure it that it will stay protected against Null Reference Error?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check if there are 4 subitems in focused item, something like this :

```
 ListView lv = (ListView)sender;
 if (lv.FocusedItem != null && lv.FocusedItem.SubItems.Count > 3)
 {
   textBox2.Text = lv.FocusedItem.SubItems[3].Text;
   textBox3.Text = lv.FocusedItem.SubItems[0].Text;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a private method, so it cannot be added as an event handler to any events unless you do so from your own class.  Therefore, it will not receive events from anywhere except where you tell it to in your code.  It will not receive events for ListView controls on other forms (unless you instruct it to do so).  If your only concern is stopping null reference exceptions, you simply need to add checking to see if the properties are null.  The ListView control on your own form will still potentially raise the event when there is no FocusedItem, or the focused item does not have every expected sub item.  Therefore, to be totally safe, you could do something like this:

```
private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (sender != null)
    {
        ListView lv = (ListView)sender;
        if ((lv.FocusedItem != null) && (lv.FocusedItem.SubItems.Count >= 4))
        {
            textBox2.Text = lv.FocusedItem.SubItems[3].Text;
            textBox3.Text = lv.FocusedItem.SubItems[0].Text;
        }
    }
}
```